# Wake from sleep with external Keyboard or mouse after these have been unplugged and replugged on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, sleep, wake-up

I am working with two computers, an Asus laptop with Windows 10 and a Dell Optiflex Desktop PC with Ubuntu 20.04. The Asus laptop is also used as if it was a a desktop computer, i.e. the lid is always closed, so it is inconvenient to open and close it to use the built-in keyboard or power button. For both computers, I use an external keyboard and mouse.

During the day, I have to switch between the two computers. When I switch computers, I set the one I will stop using for a while (say, computer A) in sleep mode, I unplug the external keyboard and mouse and plug them to computer B (since I do not have a KVM switch). When I want to use again computer A, I do the inverse operation - I unplug the mouse and keyboard from computer B and plug them to A.

Now, suppose I set to sleep the Windows 10 laptop, I unplug the keyboard and mouse, plug them to the Ubuntu PC, then replug everything to the Windows 10 laptop. If I do this, I am no longer able to wake-up the Windows laptop from sleep. Note that if I set the Windows laptop to sleep *without* unplugging anything, I am perfectly able to wake it up (both with the mouse and the external keyboard). Is there any way to wake-up my Windows laptop after all the unplugging/replugging? Is there any other workaround I could use that does not involve opening the lid of my laptop? E.g. wake-up after plugging a pendrive, if such a thing exists.

My question is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1294758/wake-from-suspend-from-usb-keyboard-stops-working-after-unplugging-replugging-ke) one, where, however, the problem involved a computer running Linux (while mine is running Windows 10) and using a KVM switch (which I do not have).

Comment: What's likely occurring is when Sleep occurs, it registers the peripherals at a specific address space and when they're unplugged, then plugged back in, they're assigned a new address space because the original one is still occupied until the OS resumes from sleep, resulting in the OS having no means to communicate with the new address space until it comes out of it's sleep state.